# Is it possible to get cart abandonment statistics? What is the best cart abandonment solution?

Tags: notification

Magento 1.9.1.0

Is there a way to get cart abandonment statistics? I don't mean the number of visitors but the actual not finished sales. And what do you recommend as a solution that would send out a reminder (you have items in your cart - click here to check-out) kind of a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use events sales_quote_add_item and sales_order_place_after log entries for statistics and compare quote items

Here are some free solution

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/abandoned-cart-follow-up-emails-1.html

https://github.com/azurams/WBL_AbandonedCart

Comment: Thank you for the info. I looked in the database and I can't find the things you mentioned there. Is it possible it is called differently in Magento 1.9.1.0?

Comment: @Allysin these are events not tables , if you want to look for that data you can look in sales_flat_quote. look for active quotes with  $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/quote_collection');
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('items_count', array('neq' => '0'))
                       ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.is_active', '1')
                       ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.store_id',array('eq'=>$store))
                       ->addSubtotal($store)
                       ->setOrder('updated_at');

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. What are "events"? Do I find this in the database or elsewhere? This is not making much sense to me...Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: easy way would be install the above free plugins and amend them as per your need , to answer what are events https://www.pierrefay.com/magento-training/event-observer.html

Comment: I will accept your answer even-though this is NOT what I was looking for....it seems that everyone is just after getting their reputation points...

Comment: @Allysin i would be happy to help if that does't solves your issue , then you need to elaborate your question as you can find all the statistics magento reports section and free solutions that i listed dose the job of sending reminders

Answer (score 0):

This is a good one: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/triggmine-email-workflows-made-perfectly-easy.html

It also offers other campaigns like Win-Back clients, etc...